# How to set geolocation in headless chrome mode?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, geolocation

I need to run UI autotests in headless mode in chrome browser. But the standard settings

```
options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation", 1);
options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.managed_default_content_settings.geolocation", 1);
```

in headless mode do not work.

I read that we can set it to manual geolocation by emulating actions in devtools.
My code C#:

```
var devTools = Driver as IDevTools;
var session = devTools!.GetDevToolsSession();

var typeList = new[] { PermissionType.Geolocation };

var commandPermission = new GrantPermissionsCommandSettings();

commandPermission.Permissions = typeList;
commandPermission.Origin = "https://www.gps-coordinates.net/my-location";
session.SendCommand(commandPermission);

var command = new SetGeolocationOverrideCommandSettings();
command.Latitude = 35.689487;
command.Longitude = 139.691706;
command.Accuracy = 100;
session.SendCommand(command);
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work.
Could you suggest what could be the problem?

**

### UPDATED

**
As a result, the code above worked, but I still could not click on the button, due to the lock screen with a message about permission to determine geolocation.

As a result, with the help of a JS script, I was able to set the geolocation

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver;
            js.ExecuteScript("navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition = (cb) => {cb({ coords: { latitude: 35, longitude: 139 } })}");
```

Comment: Is there an error? If yes, please share your ErrorMessage

Answer (score 0):

That should be possible using the Chrome-devtoools-protocoll method `Emulation.setGeolocationOverride` (see https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Emulation/#method-setGeolocationOverride)

That's actually what you're doing. Maybe 1000 is too big for accuracy, try using `1`